# Jquery Autocomplete doesnt work for me

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-autocomplete

I've followed [this guide](http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/12/10/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-django/) (autocomplete guide for django), i got several of items in my database which im trying to get, so i write **AB** in my input, i get 4 responses. But when i then add another **A** -> **ABA** nothing happens.

[Explaining pic](http://oi56.tinypic.com/o5yia1.jpg), here you can see the rotating loader. And it doesnt seem to make any requests towards my server.

Comment: have checked the official jquery ui site for autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote the autocomplete has a gif that shows while reading from source, try adding gibberish and see the gif

Comment: jquery, not the ui docs yes. I've tried different forms, and changed it but i still got the weird little error.

I dont get it if i use a normal var with a static list.

Answer (score 0):

It look the widget is waiting for the answer but not getting it.

First check if the AJAX request for 'ABA' is done. You can check this:

- in the console view of FireBug (a Firefox extension)
- in the output of the Django development server if you use it
- in the access log of the web server you use.

If the request is sent, check the server response code. If there's an error check the error. Your problem is on the server side (probably in your `view`).

If the request is not sent, the problem is with the Javascript part (less probable) not sending the request.

If the server response is receive, the problem is also with the Javascript part having problem reading, etc. the response. The response could be in bad format.

You should use Firebug or something similar (in Chrome, Safari, etc.) to help you with your issue. it will be lot more easier to debug.